# Can Azure devops resolve hostnames of postgresql flexible servers in private DNS zone with private access enabled?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-private-link

I am using a combination of Azure devops and terraform to provision our environments on the fly and configure them.
During the various stages of our pipeline we are creating a postgreSQL DB felxible server and subsequently creating a user on it in the next stage/job.

The problem is if the flexible server has public access, Azure pipelines is able re resolve hostname and create user. But when we launch the Db with private access and a private DNS zone, the pipeline is unable to resolve the hostname and thus failing to create a user.

Is it possible for Azure devops (azure hosted agents) to resolve hostnames for the flexible server in this case?
PS : I looked into private endpoint but it is probably not available for flexible servers as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, public agents (Azure Hosted) cannot connect to any Azure resources that are protected behind a Private Endpoint with public access disabled.

You will need to set up self-hosted build agents which you do need to give access to the private endpoints and the private DNS zones.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Any idea regarding a workaround or if there will be a feature for this in the future?

Comment: the workaround - not really a workaround but the actual solution - are self hosted agents.